# Significado de "droga" en siglo XVIII

Tags: significado, historia

El general y ministro, Conde de Lacy, mencionó «drogas» en la carta abajo mostrada.

> (...) porque antiguamente aquel país se ha poblado con habitantes de Siberia, en donde se hacía todo el comercio de **drogas** que se vendían en la feria de Novgorod...

En su época ¿podía la palabra «**drogas**» significar algo diferente de lo que entendemos hoy por drogas?

[image: La carta de Lacy]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En un diccionario de esa época, dice esto:

> DROGA. s. f. Qualquier género de especería; como incienso , goma , benjuí y otras varias especies aromáticas , simples , ó compuestas. Y tambien se comprehenden en esta palabra otros varios géneros de cosas ; como maná , xalapa , ruibarbo , bermellon , cardenillo , añil, &c. *Aromata , pharmacum.*
>
> - *ACADEMIA USUAL* (1780)

como puedes ver, su significado solía ser mucho más amplio.