# Evolución del concepto de "droga" en el idioma español

Tags: historia, sustantivos

[La última pregunta de Aaron Brick](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26444/12637) nos ha puesto de manifiesto que el concepto de *droga* hace un par de siglos no era el mismo que el concepto actual. Así, en el *Diccionario de Autoridades* leemos:

> DROGA. s. f. Qualquier género de especería: como Incienso, goma, benjuí y otras varias espécies aromáticas, simples ò compuestas. Y tambien se comprehenden en esta palabra otros varios géneros de cosas: como Maná, xaiápa, ruibarbo, bermellon, cardenillo, añil.

Esta acepción, digamos, inocua de la palabra es la que generó posteriormente la palabra *[droguería](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ECrYtnv)* como "tienda en que se venden drogas", o su evolución en España: "tienda en la que se venden productos de limpieza y pinturas".

Sin embargo, a pesar de que esta acepción de la palabra *[droga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ECdTcOk)* se mantiene, hoy día la acepción con la que la conocemos mayoritariamente es otra:

> Sustancia o preparado medicamentoso de efecto estimulante, deprimente, narcótico o alucinógeno.

Es más, yo casi diría que se llama *droga* a cualquier sustancia que provoque adicción o, como dice la tercera acepción, una "afición obsesiva".

Así pues, ¿cómo evolucionó el concepto de *droga* desde entonces hasta hoy para llegar a adquirir la acepción actual? ¿Cuál fue el punto de inflexión que hizo que la palabra modificase su significado?

Mi teoría: en el *Autoridades* aparece otra acepción de droga. La siguiente:

> DROGA. Metaphoricamente vale embuste, mentira disfrazada y artificiosa, pretexto engañosamente fingido, y compuesto: y assi del que no trata verdád, y está en mala opinión, se dice, que quanto habla o hace es una pura droga.

Esta acepción de hecho se mantiene en el DLE pero está marcada como en desuso. Sin embargo, dado que una droga (de las alucinógenas) te puede hacer vivir una realidad falsa, disfrazada y artificiosa, ¿pudo influir este significado en la creación de la acepción actual?

Comment: Yo más bien creo que es un uso influido por el inglés, idioma en que *drug* significa *medicamento* y de ahí pasó también a significar lo que nosotros llamamos "droga".